# Set positive class in xgboost.XGBClassifier()

Tags: python, xgboost

Is possible to decide which class in xgboost.XGBClassifier() willl be taken as the positive one ?

Comment: Hi Sara, welcome to stack overflow. May you share your code ? what you've done so far and how's your data look like ? especially you target variable

Comment: If you are asking this because you want to set `scale_pos_weight`, you might want to see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65304302/how-can-i-know-which-is-the-positive-class-value-and-negative-class-value-for-xg

Comment: Hi! I saw it but I really just want to decide which class is positive and negative.

Comment: I think it is considering label `0` as negative class and label `1` as positive. But you said _It is taking the class 0 as positive_, how did you find out?

Comment: Hi! Thanks everybody for the help. Actually it was taking the class 1 as positive after a further check. Anyway, I was quite surprised to not have found the option to set the desire value as positive.

Comment: There are some options if you want to manually modify your data such that all 0 labels become 1 and vice versa. You can do that with `y.replace({1:0, 0:1})`, or using label encoder. Hence you can trick XGBClassifier.